# Javascript FundMe Solidity Test code troubleshooting

Tags: solidity, contract-development, hardhat, nodejs

**Code 1 returns error while Code 2 doesn't, why?**
**CODE 1**

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

describe("FundMe", function () {
    let fundMe
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator
    const ethAmount = "1000000000000000000"

    beforeEach(async function () {
        // Get the deployer's signer
        deployer = await ethers.provider.getSigner()
        // Deploy contracts using Hardhat fixture with "all" tag
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        // Get instances of FundMe and MockV3Aggregator contracts
        fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt(
            "FundMe",
            (await deployments.get("FundMe")).address,
            deployer,
        )
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContractAt(
            "MockV3Aggregator",
            (await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator")).address,
            deployer,
        )
    })

    describe("constructor", async () => {
        it("sets the aggregator addresses correctly", async function () {
            // Check if the price feed in FundMe contract is set correctly
            const response = await fundMe.priceFeed()
            assert.equal(response, await mockV3Aggregator.getAddress())
        })
    })

    // Test cases for the fund function
    it("Fund", async () => {
        // Expect the fund function to revert with the specified error message
        await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
            "You need to spend more ETH!",
        )
    })

    it("Fund amount successful", async () => {
        // Fund the contract with a specific amount
        await fundMe.fund({ value: ethAmount })
        // Check if the amount funded by the deployer matches the expected amount
        const response = await fundMe.addressToAmountFunded(deployer.address)
        assert.equal(response.toString(), ethAmount.toString())
    })

    it("adds funder's address to array", async () => {
        // Fund the contract with a specific amount
        await fundMe.fund({ value: ethAmount })
        // Check if the deployer's address is added to the list of funders
        const response = await fundMe.funders(0)
        assert.equal(response, deployer.address)
    })

    describe("withdraw", async () => {
        beforeEach("withdraw", async () => {
            await fundMe.fund({ value: ethAmount })
        })

        it("withdraws total balance to single founder while resetting addresses array", async () => {
            const startingFundMeBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(
                fundMe.target,
            )

            const startingDeployerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(
                deployer.address,
            )

            const transactionResponse = await fundMe.withdraw()

            const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
            const { gasUsed, effectiveGasPrice } = transactionReceipt
            const gasCost = ethers.utils.mul(gasUsed, effectiveGasPrice)

            const endingFundMeBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(
                fundMe.target,
            )

            const endingDeployerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(
                deployer.adddress,
            )

            assert.equal(endingFundMeBalance.toString(), "0")
            assert.equal(
                startingDeployerBalance.add(startingFundMeBalance).toString(),
                endingDeployerBalance.add(gasCost).toString(),
            )
        })
    })
})
```

**CODE 2, exact error fixed when the last it statement is changed. why?**

```
it("withdraws total balance to single founder while resetting addresses array", async () => {
    const startingFundMeBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(fundMe.target);
    const startingDeployerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(deployer.address);
    const transactionResponse = await fundMe.withdraw();
    const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1);

    console.log("Transaction Receipt:", transactionReceipt);

    const gasUsed = transactionReceipt.gasUsed;
    const effectiveGasPrice = transactionReceipt.effectiveGasPrice;

    console.log("Gas Used:", gasUsed);
    console.log("Effective Gas Price:", effectiveGasPrice);

    if (gasUsed === undefined || effectiveGasPrice === undefined) {
        console.error("Gas information is missing.");
        return;
    }

    const gasCost = ethers.utils.mul(gasUsed, effectiveGasPrice);
    const endingFundMeBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(fundMe.target);
    const endingDeployerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(deployer.address);

    console.log("Ending FundMe Balance:", endingFundMeBalance.toString());
    console.log("Ending Deployer Balance:", endingDeployerBalance.toString());

    assert.equal(endingFundMeBalance.toString(), "0");
    assert.equal(
        startingDeployerBalance
            .add(startingFundMeBalance)
            .toString(),
        endingDeployerBalance.add(gasCost).toString()
    );
});
```

**FundMe.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "./PriceConverter.sol";

error FundMe__NotOwner();

contract FundMe {
    using PriceConverter for uint256;

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address[] public funders;

    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;

    // Could we make this constant?  /* hint: no! We should make it immutable! */
    address public immutable i_owner;
    uint256 public constant MINIMUM_USD = 50 * 10 ** 18;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        // require(msg.sender == owner);
        if (msg.sender != i_owner) revert FundMe__NotOwner();
        _;
    }

    constructor(AggregatorV3Interface priceFeedAddress) {
        i_owner = msg.sender;

        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeedAddress);
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        require(
            msg.value.getConversionRate(priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD,
            "You need to spend more ETH!"
        );
        // require(PriceConverter.getConversionRate(msg.value) >= MINIMUM_USD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }

    // function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
    //     // ETH/USD price feed address of Sepolia Network.
    //     AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306);
    //     return priceFeed.version();
    // }

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        for (
            uint256 funderIndex = 0;
            funderIndex < funders.length;
            funderIndex++
        ) {
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        funders = new address[](0);
        // // transfer
        // payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
        // // send
        // bool sendSuccess = payable(msg.sender).send(address(this).balance);
        // require(sendSuccess, "Send failed");
        // call
        (bool callSuccess, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{
            value: address(this).balance
        }("");
        require(callSuccess, "Call failed");
    }

    // Explainer from: https://solidity-by-example.org/fallback/
    // Ether is sent to contract
    //      is msg.data empty?
    //          /   \
    //         yes  no
    //         /     \
    //    receive()?  fallback()
    //     /   \
    //   yes   no
    //  /        \
    //receive()  fallback()

    fallback() external payable {
        fund();
    }

    receive() external payable {
        fund();
    }
}

// Concepts we didn't cover yet (will cover in later sections)
// 1. Enum
// 2. Events
// 3. Try / Catch
// 4. Function Selector
// 5. abi.encode / decode
// 6. Hash with keccak256
// 7. Yul / Assembly
```